# GDB is showing 1 Thread in non threaded application

Tags: c++, multithreading, gdb

I was debugging my app with gdb. 
 I used break main 
So it can break when main is called. 
Know if I use `thread info` it shows that thread count is 1.

How a thread is starting before main ?
I don't have any thread call in my call so from where thread is getting created. I am using these libs

> sqlite , curl , pcre , c-client

Update 
I have written a sample program to test that if all program start with single thread

```
 #include<iostream>
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
  std:: cout<<"Will I have any thread";
  return 0;
}
```

but when I debug it with gdb

```
    (gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400783: file threadtest.cpp, line 3.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/vivek/Desktop/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe728) at threadtest.cpp:3
3         std:: cout<<"Will I have any thread";
(gdb) info threads
* 1 process 21608  main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe728) at threadtest.cpp:3
(gdb)
```

it doesn't show the same information. It show 1 process not 1 thread.

**When I compile it with -lpthread it show 1 thread.**

So program start with one  thread when we use lpthread ?
or GDB behaves like that ?

Comment: Could it be, that this thread is your main thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All programs have at least 1 thread, the main thread. The program is started before main since the C++ runtime does some initializing before `main()` starts, like calling all global objects which have constructors.

Comment: When I use -lpthread for linking in sample program gdb show 1 thread. But when not it show one process. So program start with one  thread when we use lpthread ?
or GDB behaves like that ?

Comment: There is always a thread (the main thread, as @Maister mentioned) within a process. But GDB can't tell you anything about threads unless you link with a threading library.

Answer (score 1):

The operating system creates a process space with one thread and calls the application loader to execute the application in that thread, which in turns performs some initial setup (gathering command line arguments into `argc` and `argv`, for example) and calls `main`.

Answer (score 0):

For the sample App when I compile it with -lpthread it shows 1 thread is running. 
So lpthread is playing key point here.

```
 (gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400793: file threadtest.cpp, line 3.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/vivek/Desktop/a.out 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe728) at threadtest.cpp:3
3         std:: cout<<"Will I have any thread";
(gdb) info threads
* 1 Thread 0x2aaaaaac8bb0 (LWP 21649)  main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe728)
    at threadtest.cpp:3
(gdb)
```